# The fastest way to convert types in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi what is the fastest way to convert string to appropriate types in DataFrame? I would like to make it automatically without specifying which columns should have a given type. Currently I'm using `ast.literal_eval()` for each cell but it's very slow for big dataframes (I'm using this only for columns whose dtype is `object`). Are there any faster alternatives?

Comment: It depends on how much flexibility you need. Can you give an example of data that you'd like to convert to another type? For example, `ast.literal_eval()` supports parsing a string like `"[1, 2, 3]"` into a list. Is that something you need?

Comment: Yes this is why I''m using this `ast` module

Comment: Can you show a snippet of what you're expecting and what you currently see?

Comment: @HedgeLow Maybe you could use `json.loads()` if your data is similar enough to JSON to get away with it. If you need to parse arbitrary Python literals, then `ast.literal_eval()` is unavoidable.